# Android Browser will refresh when going back into the web broswer

Tags: android, browser, webkit

I have a website that is designed to run on a mobile phone.  We are seeing an issue with Android based handsets.  My application is wizard driven a user will log in to the site and start filling out our wizard driven form.  Towards the end of our form we require the user to use his handset to take a picture and upload it.  The issue we are having is that when users return to the browser at time it will automatically refresh the web page. By design we return the user to the main main if it is a new request.  Is it possible to stop this behavior we would simply like the user to return to the browser after taking a picture ortaking a phone / call or text.  We don't need the browser to refresh the user has already entered data.  We would prefer the user to manually refresh if they need to or just hit the next button in our application.  Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to use a cookie to bring them back to the previous session.

The problem in android is that an app can be killed at any time (including the browser), depending on the resource requirements of the phone.  This also depends on how the user operates their phone.

You cannot assume that the browser can be kept open, you must engineer your solution accordingly.